# Hight chart show series data in milliseconds

Tags: graph, highcharts

Actually I have the problem in displaying the data in milliseconds on high chart. I am showing the time in x asix and for time I have 20 different values in 1 seconds I mean 20 different values in 1 min. But my graph is just displaying the data in seconds not showing the milliseconds intervals so kindly let me know how I can plot the data with milliseconds on the Line or Spline chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for you to get the labels in milliseconds, you need to set the dateTimeLabelFormats to display milliseconds as shown below

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L'
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates it http://jsfiddle.net/RcY2Q/

I hope this will help you